# Gridview text box edit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox inside the gridview. IF i enter any non-numeric values it has to show error message. How to handle this in row edit event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx) to check for numeric value.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
            ErrorMessage="Enter only Numbers" ValidationExpression="[0-9]*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Don't forget to add a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator%28VS.80%29.aspx) too, if empty Text is also invalid.